# Fill PDF form field with Hebrew text (RTL)

Tags: pdf, itext

I tried to use iText 7 community to check if it supports filling PDF form fields in Hebrew. For some reason, I can't make it work.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, false);
form.setGenerateAppearance(true);

form.getField("test").setValue("\u05de\u05d9\u05db\u05d0\u05dc");

form.flattenFields();
pdfDoc.close();
```

The PDF is a blank PDF page including only one text field with the following properties:

- Font Adobe Hebrew
- Text direction RTL

I tried with and without flattening fields.

When fields are not flattened, after opening the resulting PDF using Acrobat Reader, I see my field but it is empty. Only after I click on the field, the content of the field appears correctly. When I view the PDF on Chrome, the field doesn't appear (or it may be there but no text inside).

When fields are flattened, after opening the resulting PDF using Acrobat Reader, the field doesn't appear at all.

I precise that I created the PDF using Acrobat DC.

Any idea what is going on here?

---

**EDIT**: The test PDF can be downloaded from [here](https://expirebox.com/download/b690857b98af56b3df4cf1fe260d5eed.html)

Comment: Please also share the pdf in question.

Comment: @mkl Done. Thanks

Comment: Does your code work with Latin text?

Comment: Yes. No issue with latin text

Comment: Is the font Adobe Hebrew fully embedded? (If you want to test embedded font behavior: Acrobat should have an option to ignore locally installed fonts.)

Comment: The content of the field is set. Before clicking on the field on Acrobat Reader, I see a blue rectangle representing the field. However, the text content doesn't show up until I click on the field. I unchecked the "Use local fonts" property - same thing. According to the document properties (tab Fonts), the font Adobe Hebrew is fully embedded.

Comment: The only way I found to make it work is to set needAppearance to true. However, text appears reversed in Chrome.

Comment: Also, field.getFont() returns null. Does that mean no font is set for the field? This is weird because I do see the font Adobe Hebrew set on Acrobat DC.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a font (not all fonts support IDENTITY_H, but Arial does). On windows this will look like this:

```
        PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

And then set the font to field:

```
form.getField("test").setValue("\u05de\u05d9\u05db\u05d0\u05dc").setFont(f);
```

This worked for me